# In Eclipse, in the Call Hierarchy, way to expand all?

Tags: eclipse

I'm individually clicking through each caller's caller.
Would prefer to just "expand all" and bottom out.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible as of now. Possibly because the node searched further and loaded only when expanded. An Expand All button will be very slow. However, if you have can justify the need with your business case, the JDT UI team will be more than happy to provide it. Please [open an enhancement request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi) with them.

Comment: The business case is very simple: spending 3 seconds of clicking instead of 180 seconds. Surely developers can be left to decide whether to expand all or not?

Answer (score 4):

There is no button for that, but you can get very similar result by selecting the root (called method), then use the keyboard shortcut for expanding a tree: SHIFT+RIGHT_ARROW. Repeat several times, staying on the root, and all callers of the next level are shown.

It is a standard shortcut in Gnome applications (I'm on Ubuntu), so I don't know it this will work on other operating systems.

Comment: works on Windows 7, Eclipse Oxygen. but I have to click also arrown down to go to next node.

Comment: Meta/Alt-Right_Arrow on macs

Answer (score 3):

I am using Luna eclipse in windows 7.

Once the Call hierarchy is done, then go to Call hierarchy window press `home` button then press key <kbd>*</kbd> (asterisk) until expanding all.

This is faster than pressing combination right and down arrow key.